# TS -- Is it possible to ensure that a file exports conform to a certain shape?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if it's possible to enforce the shape of an ESM file's exports without turning it into a class export, e.g. I'd want `square.ts`, `triagle.ts`, `circle.ts`, etc to all have the same export shapes:

```
{
  numSides: () => number,
  to3D: () => 3DShape,
}
```

`square.ts`:

```
export function numSides() {
  return 4;
}

export function to3D() {
  return new Cube();
}
```

With Common JS I could do something like:

```
module.exports = { numSides, to3D } as shape
```

Trying the same thing in ESM throws an error on `as shape`

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't possible directly, I ended up just casting all of the imports in an `index.ts` file, which may be a helpful approach for anyone else that finds this:

`index.ts:`

```
type shapeExport = {
  numSides: () => number,
  to3D: () => 3DShape,
}

import * as circle from './circle';
import * as triangle from './triangle';
import * as square from './square';

const [ eCircle, eTriangle, eSquare ] = [ circle, triangle, square ] as shapeExport[];

export { eCircle, eTriangle, eSquare };
```

A bit verbose, but it solves the problem.